# Display resolution options disappeared after upgrade to Sierra

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution, macos

After I upgraded an MBPr to 10.12 Sierra, the 4k external display connected to it shows significantly less options under Display > Resolution > Scaled (pressing Option to see the resolutions). Before, I always used it at resolutions between 2160p and 1080p, generally 1440p, but those are gone now.[image: Preferences window showing display resolutions, including 2160p and 1080p but nothing in between]

What could cause this? How would you troubleshoot it? I'd rather fix it without having to force the resolution in configuration files (like I had to do years ago), but that'd be better than this situation.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a problem in Sierra, and many people are having this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I purchase a new MacPro (the little black trash can) and shortly after, chose to install the Sierra update. Upon restart, it would not recognize my Apple Cinema's high res settings. After 3 hours with Apple tech support, they filed a report to Apple engineering who solved my problem with this solution:

- Shut down your machine
- Unplug all of your monitor's connections (in my case, 2 USB and 1 Thunderbolt) and reconnect using only the ports on the RIGHT side of the Mac.
- Voila! They said they are aware of the glitch, are attempting to fix it, and until now, this should work.

Comment: the question refered to a MBP, and this answer is only relevant to a MacPro, but still will be useful for someone. BTW, what a bug...

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution I found in a [MacRumors thread](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/users-report-loss-of-hidpi-scaling-on-external-displays-in-macos-sierra.2000464/page-2#post-23574020) is listed below. Note I have not tested this myself as I do not have either Sierra or a monitor that would support such a resolution.

> This command in Terminal and a reboot fixed it for me on Sierra.
>
> ```
> sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist DisplayResolutionEnabled -bool true
> ```

Also try checking the "Show low resolution modes" option.